# Algorithm for calculating the Grundy value of a green-hackenbush graph

Tags: algorithms, game-theory

I need an algorithm to convert a green hackenbush graph to it's equivalent tree so that I can find the Grundy value of the Graph using colon principle.

I thought of finding the bridges in the given graph and compressing cycles into one node using the fusion principle but I fail to implement it when there are cycles within cycles.

Can someone provide an easy to implement algorithm that can find the Grundy value (using Sprague-Grundy theorem) of a given Green - Hackenbush graph.